# Forked groovyc returned error code: -1073741819

Tags: groovy, selenium, gradle, spock, geb

I wanted to try out geb/spock for some acceptance testing and started with an initial gradle build script below:

```
apply plugin: "groovy"
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
configurations {
    testCompile.transitive = true
}
dependencies {
    groovy "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:1.6.3"
    def gebVersion = "0.6.2"
    def seleniumVersion = "2.15.0"
    // If using Spock, need to depend on geb-spock
    testCompile "org.codehaus.geb:geb-spock:$gebVersion"
    testCompile "org.spockframework:spock-core:0.5-groovy-1.7"
    // If using JUnit, need to depend on geb-junit (3 or 4)
    testCompile "org.codehaus.geb:geb-junit4:$gebVersion"
    testCompile "junit:junit-dep:4.8.2"
    // Need a driver implementation
    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:$seleniumVersion"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-support:$seleniumVersion"
}
test {
    systemProperties "geb.build.reportsDir": "$reportsDir/geb"
}
```

When I try to run the test I get the weirdest error on my windows machine that I have no clue about and in my google search didn't see anyone with this error:

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':compileTestGroovy'.
>
>   > Forked groovyc returned error code: -1073741819
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Wondering if anyone has a clue on where I should start...

**Update**
Changing groovy to `1.7.10` still caused the same error. Below is part of the stack trace produced by `-s -d` options

```
15:24:34.540 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':compileTestGroovy'
15:24:34.571 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
15:24:34.571 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
15:24:34.587 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
15:24:34.587 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
15:24:34.587 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Execution failed for task ':compileTestGroovy'.
15:24:34.602 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] > Forked groovyc returned error code: -1073741819
15:24:34.602 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
15:24:34.618 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Exception is:
15:24:34.618 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':compileTestGroovy'.
15:24:34.634 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteAct
ionsTaskExecuter.java:68)
15:24:34.634 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTas
kExecuter.java:46)
15:24:34.649 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecut
ionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:34)
15:24:34.649 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter$1.run(CacheLockHandlin
gTaskExecuter.java:34)
15:24:34.665 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$2.create(DefaultCacheAccess.java:200)
15:24:34.665 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:17
2)
15:24:34.681 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:19
8)
15:24:34.681 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersis
tentDirectoryStore.java:111)
15:24:34.696 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOpera
tion(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:83)
15:24:34.696 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.CacheLockHandlingTaskExecuter.execute(CacheLockHandl
ingTaskExecuter.java:32)
15:24:34.712 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExe
cuter.java:55)
15:24:34.727 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecute
r.java:57)
15:24:34.727 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySo
urceFilesTaskExecuter.java:41)
15:24:34.743 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNo
ActionsExecuter.java:51)
15:24:34.743 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecute
r.java:52)
15:24:34.759 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostO
nceTaskExecuter.java:42)
15:24:34.759 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:250
)
15:24:34.774 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.executeTask(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:192)

15:24:34.774 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.doExecute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:177)
15:24:34.790 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:83)
15:24:34.821 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:36
)
15:24:34.868 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
15:24:34.868 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
15:24:34.884 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
15:24:34.884 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter$1.run(TaskCacheLo
ckHandlingBuildExecuter.java:31)
15:24:34.899 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess$1.create(DefaultCacheAccess.java:111)
15:24:34.899 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:126)
15:24:34.899 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:109)
15:24:34.915 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirector
yStore.java:103)
15:24:34.915 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(Default
TaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
15:24:34.931 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.execute(TaskCache
LockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:29)
15:24:34.931 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
15:24:34.946 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
15:24:34.946 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
15:24:34.962 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
15:24:34.962 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
15:24:34.977 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
15:24:34.977 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:155
)
15:24:34.993 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:110)
15:24:34.993 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:78)
15:24:34.993 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.execute(RunBuildAction.java:42)
15:24:35.009 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.execute(RunBuildAction.java:28)
15:24:35.009 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:32)
15:24:35.024 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:21)
15:24:35.024 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLoggingAction.execute(CommandLineAction
Factory.java:238)
15:24:35.040 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLoggingAction.execute(CommandLineAction
Factory.java:222)
15:24:35.040 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
15:24:35.056 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.EntryPoint$1.execute(EntryPoint.java:53)
15:24:35.056 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.EntryPoint$1.execute(EntryPoint.java:51)
15:24:35.056 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.Execution.execute(Execution.java:28)
15:24:35.071 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:39)
15:24:35.071 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
15:24:35.087 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:51)
15:24:35.087 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:33)
15:24:35.087 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:24)
15:24:35.102 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Caused by: : Forked groovyc returned error code: -1073741819
15:24:35.102 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
15:24:35.118 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
15:24:35.118 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ant.BasicAntBuilder.nodeCompleted(BasicAntBuilder.java:71)
15:24:35.134 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AntBuilderDelegate.nodeCompleted(DefaultIsolatedAntBuilder.g
roovy:173)
15:24:35.134 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AntGroovyCompiler$_execute_closure1.doCall(AntGroovyCo
mpiler.groovy:60)
15:24:35.149 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:136)
15:24:35.149 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:85)
15:24:35.165 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil$configure.call(Unknown Source)
15:24:35.165 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultIsolatedAntBuilder.execute(DefaultIsolatedAntBuilder.
groovy:113)
15:24:35.165 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.IsolatedAntBuilder$execute.call(Unknown Source)
15:24:35.181 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.AntGroovyCompiler.execute(AntGroovyCompiler.groovy:57)

15:24:35.181 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.IncrementalJavaCompilerSupport.execute(IncrementalJava
CompilerSupport.java:42)
15:24:35.196 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.GroovyCompile.compile(GroovyCompile.java:60)
15:24:35.196 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.ja
va:196)
15:24:35.212 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:102)
15:24:35.212 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:93)
15:24:35.227 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.GroovyCompile_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
15:24:35.227 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.util.ReflectionUtil.invoke(ReflectionUtil.groovy:23)
15:24:35.243 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$4.execute(Annota
tionProcessingTaskFactory.java:150)
15:24:35.243 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$4.execute(Annota
tionProcessingTaskFactory.java:145)
15:24:35.259 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:495)
15:24:35.259 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:484)
15:24:35.274 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteAct
ionsTaskExecuter.java:60)
15:24:35.274 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]        ... 54 more
15:24:35.290 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
15:24:35.290 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
15:24:35.290 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
15:24:35.306 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
15:24:35.306 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 18.014 secs
```

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, spock-core:0.5-groovy-1.7 won't work with Groovy 1.6. I recommend to use 1.7.10 instead. Also, running the build with -s -d might give a clue.

Comment: I had tried changing to 1.7.10 but that also produced same errors. I've added part of the stack trace by building with `-s -d` options

Comment: Does this ONLY happen on Windows?  Also, did you follow Peter's suggestion and run the build in debug mode?

Comment: Please paste the full stack trace.

Comment: May I ask you where you got the `testCompile.transitive = true` from? This is the default, and I'm wondering why so many people have it in their build scripts.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser I got that from here: https://github.com/geb/geb-example-gradle I'm working with that build script and code. I've been able to confirm that this problem is only happening on my windows box as I tried on my ubuntu box at home without a problem.

Comment: Isn't the error code in the log the exact same error code in Windows representing an access violation?

Comment: Yeah, thats what I felt when searching for it on google. However, all the folders, except the jar's downloaded by gradle are in C drive which is accessible. Is there a way to change the path where gradle downloads the jars? I can try changing that to see if error goes away

Comment: If it is some sort of access violation,it would be an attempt to access an address in memory that should not be accessible.  I don't believe such an error would refer to an area on the hard drive.  To answer your question, you can change the location gradle uses to store downloaded jars by setting your GRADLE_USER_HOME environment variable, but I would not bother in this case as that isn't likely to solve your problem, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

I've been facing a similar issue (same exception) and solved it disabling groovyc forks for both main and test classes (based on this link http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/gradle_m6_and_forked_groovyc_returned_error_code_1_when_using_spock).

You may set this in your `build.gradle` script.

```
compileGroovy.groovyOptions.fork = false
compileTestGroovy.groovyOptions.fork = false
```

**Note** (as it is mentioned in the linked post): *"However, this mode has other limitations. For example, Groovy compiler plugins (and therefore Spock) apparently don't work."*

Hope it helps,

Frederic